# Create a function in R

Tags: r, function

How do I create the following function in R?

```
f(1)=1
f(2)=2
f(3)=3
f(4)=1
f(5)=2
f(6)=3
f(7)=1
f(8)=2
f(9)=3
```

and so on...

I have tried to use different loops, but have not been able to do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Myfunc <- function(x) (x + 2L) %% 3L + 1L
```

Testing

```
Myfunc(1)
## [1] 1
Myfunc(2)
## [1] 2
Myfunc(3)
## [1] 3
Myfunc(1:9)
## [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know R but it can be done with Mod3 easily:

```
function modThree(x) {
   var mod = x%3;
   if(mod == 0) return 3;
   return mod;
}
```

Comment: For someone who doesn't know R, you're pretty close to R syntax. Make your first like `modThree = function() {`, get rid of `var` (don't have to declare things) and wrap your returns in parens `return(3)` and `return(mod)`, and you've got a valid R function.

Comment: I've actually also used Mod3 in my answer... Either-way, you can modify this to `modThree <- function (x) { mod = x%%3 ;ifelse(mod == 0, 3 , mod) }` and then it''ll work